# Wrong Method for Laravel Route, change the method in form

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I have a problem with Laravel 8 and AdminLTE. Basically, I installed Admin LTE and an object Editos. I have two buttons in this menu : ADD edito and EDIT. Both redirect to the same form, but with a different Laravel Route. So my form.blade.php starts with :

```
<form 
        method="post" 
        action="{{ Route::currentRouteName() === 'editos.edit' ? route('editos.update', $edito->id) : route('editos.store') }}">

        @if(Route::currentRouteName() === 'editos.edit')
            @method('PUT')
        @endif
        
        @csrf
```

Both buttons redirects to correct routes. The ADD function works perfectly : I fill the form and press submit button, the 'editos.store function with POST method is called and the edito is stored in my database.
But when i click on EDIT, it goes with the edit route (ok), it loads the actual fields (ok), but i click on submit, it calls the 'editos.update' route (ok) BUT i got this Laravel error message :

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.
http://hibooexpert.home/admin/editos/update/11?_method=PUT&_token=wGibILt5dHCfIOWDMNIuiTYXNL4quDagNJAob4t2&body=%3Cp%3EJe%20suis%26nbsp%3B%20un%20texte%20exempleqsfdqdfsqf%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A&categories%5B0%5D=2&excerpt=sqdfsqdf&image=image00004.jpeg&meta_description=General&meta_keywords=keyyy&seo_title=Bonjour&slug=bonjourfsdf&tags=&title=Bonjour

My routes are defined as such in my web.php :

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::put('editos/update/{id}', [BackEditoController::class, 'update'])->name('editos.update');
        Route::name('admin')->get('/', [AdminController::class, 'index']);
        Route::name('purge')->put('purge/{model}', [AdminController::class, 'purge']);
        Route::name('editos.create')->get('edito/create', [BackEditoController::class, 'create']);
        Route::name('editos.store')->post('editos/store', [BackEditoController::class, 'store']);
        Route::name('editos.edit')->get('editos/edit/{id}', [BackEditoController::class, 'edit']);
        Route::name('editos.destroy')->post('editos/destroy', [BackEditoController::class, 'destroy']);

        Route::name('editos')->get('editos', [BackEditoController::class, 'index']);
    });
    
});
```

( I just put the editos/update/ on top to try, and changed also the syntax, but putting it somewhere else doesn't work).
As you see, it's a PUT function, and it is also defined as a PUT function when I do route:list. I already tried dump-autoload and cache clear composer command.

The update function in the Controller is :

```
  public function update(EditoRequest $request, EditoRepository $repository, Edito $edito, $id = null)
    {   
        $edito = null; 
        if($id) {
            $edito = Edito::findOrFail($id);
        }
        $repository->update($edito, $request);
        return back()->with('ok', __('The edito has been successfully updated'));
    }
```

And the repository function is :

```
public function update($edito, $request)
    {
        $request->merge([
            'active' => $request->has('active'),
            'image' => basename($request->image),
        ]);
        $edito->update($request->all());
        $this->saveCategoriesAndTags($edito, $request);
    }
```

I'm completly stuck, if anyone see the solution, that would be awesome !

Answer (score -1):

From my previous experience, sometime `http://` would cause this issue, try `https://` instead and see if the problem is fixed